# jQuery Ajax request - Does not seem to make the request

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-mobile

I have this small piece of code which basically makes the request, and throws the results in `console.log` (I omitted my key and sig).

The problem is that it never seems to make the request.

Thanks for the help, I am a newbie and I'm still learning.

```
//alert('you clicked on the discgolf button');
$('#zipsubmit').click(function(){
    dgZipSearch();     // call this function perform DGCR search and 
                          populate the page with results
});

function dgZipSearch(){

    alert('foo1');

    $.ajax({
        url:'http://www.dgcr-api.com/?key=xxxxx&mode=findzip&zip=' + $('#zipcode').val() + '&rad=10&sig=yyyyyyy',
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        success: function(zip_results){
            console.log(zip_results);
        }
    });
    alert('foo2');
};
```

Comment: Are you sure that's really JSONP? What do you see in the console?

Comment: Have you tried adding the `error` callback to your code? Perhaps it would give you a bit of a clue on why this isn't working. Also, remember of checking the http code with `statusCode` if you are in fact getting an error.

Comment: do you have included the jquery in the head?

Comment: Most browsers have developer tools available if you press F12. In them you can see how AJAX requests are made in real time.

Answer (score 0):

you can also try by removing the "/" in the url. The changed url might look as below

```
http://www.dgcr-api.com?key=xxxxx&mode=findzip&.....
```

try with above url(observer the "/" i removed after www.dgcr-api.com)

also one more thing is, ajax calls are having restrictions like cross domain calls.
so please check the "crossDomain" property in below link.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score 0):

As per the [document](http://www.dgcoursereview.com/api_docs.php), the API simply responses with the JSON format unless you explicitly specify the `out` parameter to `XML`.

Therefore no need to specify the `dataType` property for the ajax request, jQuery will intelligently guess the correct datatype by the response MIME type.

Change the request like

```
$.ajax({
    url:'http://www.dgcr-api.com/?key=xxxxx&mode=findzip&zip=' + $('#zipcode').val() + '&rad=10&sig=yyyyyyy',
    success: function(zip_results){
        console.log(zip_results);
    }
});
```

and try.

For error checking you need to implement the error callback function. Additionally the API provides specific [response codes](http://www.dgcoursereview.com/api_docs.php#rcode) for convenient error handling.